# How to handle with error in r in one-way anova?

Tags: r, error-handling, anova

I have tried anova for two different ways:

1.

```
lm(os ~ cd3_abs, data = dd) %>% anova()
```

Which gives this error:

```
Error in if (ssr < 1e-10 * mss) warning("ANOVA F-tests on an essentially perfect fit are unreliable") :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

2. 

```
aov(formula = compete2 ~ cd3_abs, data = dd)
```

Which gives this error:

```
"Error in levels(x)[x] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts"
```

My data looks like:

```
    cd3_abs  OS
1   1.38     0  
2   1.19     1  
3   NA       1
4   2.32     0 
5   0.9      1
6   3.3      1
```

Comment: Your example does not reproduce your issue. Both `lm(OS ~ cd3_abs, data = dd) %>% anova()` and `aov(OS ~ cd3_abs, data = dd)` work with your data.

Comment: Are you sure you are to run a linear model? OS is a categorical variable. ie with two values ie 0,1. for linear regression, we assume `y` to be normal. How will you compute `mean(y)` for Anova?? I know you could, but do you think its correct?

Comment: The first error suggests a perfect fit, i.e. that x perfectly explains all the variation in y, although this doesn't really fit with the data you have posted..

Comment: Your data say  `cd3_abs  OS` but your model says `cd3_abs  os`.  Try correcting that. Though as others have said it's kind of a strange model.

Comment: Yeah `lm(OS ~ cd3_abs, data = dd)`  works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Two obvious issues: 1) since your `os` is binary, you should use logistic regression; 2) your `cd3_abs` column  has `NA`, which should be excluded for ANOVA. Typical code is like below:

```
glm(os ~ cd3_abs, data = dd%>%na.omit(), family=binomial)
```

Comment: This won't work either. `glmer` only works when random effects are included in the model.  Did you mean `glm(os ~ cd3_abs, data = dd, na.action = na.omit, family = binomial)` ?

Comment: @BenBolker glm() then.

Comment: also, you don't really need the `na.omit`: the default value for `na.action` is `na.omit` anyway.  As @Axeman said, the problem isn't actually reproducible with the data the OP posted ...

Comment: @BenBolker Good to know that "default value for na.action is na.omit". I would just do it for good practice, as some modelling functions don't have this setting, like aov(). Plus, OP says "My data looks like:", so I guess it is not the exactly same one used to produce the error.

Comment: Fair enough. However, if the OP doesn't give us a reproducible example, it may be best to wait until they have provided one, rather than guessing.